# How can I call a function from another ViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two ViewControllers and I need to call a func in the first from the second.

E.g. I want to add one to variable c in the first ViewController from the second:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
      }

      var c = 0
      func c_count() {
            c += 1
      }
}
```

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
      }

      @IBAction func button(_sender: Any) {
            //call c_count()
      }
}
```

I tried to use:

```
@IBAction func button(_sender: Any) {
      let vc = FirstViewController()
      vc.c_count()
}
```

but it said 'Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 (1)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach can't work because a fresh instance won't have the real data. Every time you instantiate a new `FirstViewController`, `c` will be set to 0. The instance of FVC that you want is the one that's in the view hierarchy, so even if you didn't get that breakpoint message, `c` would not be updated in the UI.

There are many ways to overcome this problem, and the one that works best will depend on the specific needs of your program. Here are a few possibilities:

1. If the view controllers are nested, you can [use the responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/using_responders_and_the_responder_chain_to_handle_events) to allow the appropriate VC to capture the `IBAction` message, even if it's triggered from a child view.
2. Save the `FirstViewController` instance to a variable where `SecondViewController` can reach it. For example, you could save a weak pointer to `FVC` into a [delegate variable](https://dilloncodes.com/delegate-pattern-in-swift) on `SVC` and formalize the relationship using a protocol.
3. Factor out the variable into some other object (either a parent of both VCs or a [singleton](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-a-singleton))
4. Access your instantiated VC via the view hierarchy and call the method directly
5. Use notifications to send a message which will run the function

Given you're new, I'd guess you want either 1 or 2. The last two can be fragile and difficult to debug, so should only be attempted if a simpler approach isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you present a second controller from a first one, you can make a protocol and delegate it.

```
protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate : NSObject {
    func cc_count()
}
```

In the second controller, you make a variable

```
weak var delegate : SecondViewControllerDelegate? = nil
```

It must be weak in order not to block memory.

Make the first controller conform to the protocol.

```
extension FirstViewController : SecondViewControllerDelegate {
   func cc_count() {
      // Execute what you need
   }
}
```

Assign delegate before presenting the second controller.

```
let vc = SecondViewController()
vc.delegate = self
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

Here you make a function call in the right place in the second controller:

```
delegate?.cc_count()
```

The second option is to transfer data via NotificationCenter.

This variant is also convenient in many cases. If necessary, I'll show you it as well.

Answer (score -2):

you can create a DataSource class that adopts the necessary protocol. Here's a basic example:

```
class MyDataSource: SomeProtocol{
   
    func doSomething(with parameter1: Int, and parameter2: String) {
        // Perform some action using the parameters or if you want to return a value
    }
}
```

In each of your UIViewControllers, create an instance of MyDataSource

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    let dataSource = MyDataSource()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    func performAction() {
        dataSource.doSomething(with: 10, and: "Hello")
    }
}
```

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    let dataSource = MyDataSource()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
    }
    
    func performAction() {
        dataSource.doSomething(with: 20, and: "World")
    }
 
}
```